dynamic linker in mac is not reading rpath
I am compiling a simple C program on m2 mac that depends on a shared library using clang on macOS. I am setting the rpath correctly using the -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/../saga flag. I've verified this by inspecting the executable using otool, which shows the correct rpath.
However, when I try to run the program, the dynamic linker (dyld) does not find the library in the specified path. The program only works when I set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the location where the library (libdynamiclib.dylib) is present.
Why is dyld not using the rpath that I've set? Am I setting the rpath incorrectly?
Here's the command I'm using to compile the program:

clang -I../saga -L../saga -ldynamiclib -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/../saga -o main main.c


Rpath only matters for lookups that are actually using @rpath, but it looks like your library isn't. Its install name is just libdynamiclib.dylib, but it needs to be @rpath/libdynamiclib.dylib.
Run this, then recompile your main binary:
install_name_tool -id '@rpath/libdynamiclib.dylib' ../saga/libdynamiclib.dylib
codesign -s - -f -o linker-signed ../saga/libdynamiclib.dylib

(The second command is just to update the default linker-generated signature, if you have your own codesigning process, then obviously just use that instead.)
And if you want a deep dive on how install names work, see this post of mine.

Thank you so much, dude! I've been banging my head against this issue since morning. You are my hero!
